# floating flag in html list

Tags: html, css

I am trying to show a flag on some items in a html list. In the screen shot below you can see the small "AF" at the bottom of the list. I would like to put that flag in selected items of the list. Despite referencing the class in the list item it will only appear at the bottom of the entire list.

[image: simple ul list]

```css
div {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 10px
}

ul {
  color: White;
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul li {
  position: relative;
  font: bold italic 22px/1.7 Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
  background: #34495E ;
}

ul li:nth-of-type(odd) {
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
  background: #283747;
}

h3 {
  padding-left: 100px;
  font: 16px/1.2 Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
  margin: 0px;
}

li p {
  font: 12px/1.5 Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding-left: 100px;
  color: #D0D3D4 ;
  margin: 0;
}

li:hover {
  background: #7D6608;
  cursor: pointer;
}

li:hover:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background: #7D6608;
  cursor: pointer;
}

span {
  position: absolute;
}

.scene_break {
  background: yellow;   
  font: 18px/1.7 Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
  color: black;
}

.scene_break:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background: yellow;   
  font: 18px/1.7 Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
  color: black;
}

li.live_cue {
  border: 4px solid yellow;
}

.cue_af {
    display: inline-block;
  background-color: #7E009A; /* Changing background color */
    font-weight: bold; /* Making font bold */
    border-radius: 5px; /* Making border radius */
    width: auto; /* Making auto-sizable width */
    height: auto; /* Making auto-sizable height */
    padding: 0px 3px 0px 3px; /* Making space around letters */
    font-size: 12px; /* Changing font size */  
}
```

```html
<ul>    
  <li><span>71</span>'+
    <h3>Test description</h3>
    <p>time: 0s</p>
    <p class="cue_af">AF</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

If I change the definition in the CSS to `li.cue_af {` then the flag will appear in the list item but all of the formatting is lost.

Comment: Try using <sub> https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_sub.asp.

Comment: Need full code due .... this much wont help. How will we place it in either table or list you've created, if we don't have the code?

Comment: try to use inline elements like <span/> or use display: inline-block  (be aware of white space issues)

Comment: @Deadpool I have added the full CSS

Comment: @mahatmanich using inline-block has got me closer. It now appears in the items and with the correct formatting but its on its own line below the other text. I just need to figure out how to right justify it on the same line as the "time" information.

Comment: @mahatmanich using <span> I was able to get it on the same line as the "time" information. Its not against the right margin but this might be an acceptable solution - thanks.

Comment: @martin Glad you got it resolved!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two solutions you could use,

**Solution:1**

You could use `position: absolute` for `.cue_af` then position it according to `li` just add the class `.flag` to any `li` and it will position automatically, check below:

```css
.flag {
  position: relative;
}
.flag::after {
    content: 'AF';
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 12px;
    background: violet;
    padding: 3px 6px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    top: 7px;
    right: 7px;
    z-index: 99;
}
div {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 10px
}

ul {
  color: White;
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul li {
  position: relative;
  font: bold italic 22px/1.7 Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
  background: #34495E ;
}

ul li:nth-of-type(odd) {
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
  background: #283747;
}

h3 {
  padding-left: 100px;
  font: 16px/1.2 Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
  margin: 0px;
}

li p {
  font: 12px/1.5 Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding-left: 100px;
  color: #D0D3D4 ;
  margin: 0;
}

li:hover {
  background: #7D6608;
  cursor: pointer;
}

li:hover:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background: #7D6608;
  cursor: pointer;
}

span {
  position: absolute;
}

.scene_break {
  background: yellow;   
  font: 18px/1.7 Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
  color: black;
}

.scene_break:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background: yellow;   
  font: 18px/1.7 Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
  color: black;
}

li.live_cue {
  border: 4px solid yellow;
}

.cue_af {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #7E009A; /* Changing background color */
    font-weight: bold; /* Making font bold */
    border-radius: 5px; /* Making border radius */
    width: auto; /* Making auto-sizable width */
    height: auto; /* Making auto-sizable height */
    padding: 0px 3px 0px 3px; /* Making space around letters */
    font-size: 12px; /* Changing font size */  
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li class="flag"><span>71</span>'+
<h3>Test description</h3>
<p>time: 0s</p>
<p class="cue_af">AF</p>
</li>
<li><span>71</span>'+
<h3>Test description</h3>
<p>time: 0s</p>
<p class="cue_af">AF</p>
</li>
<li><span>71</span>'+
<h3>Test description</h3>
<p>time: 0s</p>
<p class="cue_af">AF</p>
</li>
<li><span>71</span>'+
<h3>Test description</h3>
<p>time: 0s</p>
<p class="cue_af">AF</p>
</li>
</ul>
```

**Solutio:2**

You can remove `<p class="cue_af">AF</p>` and use `:pseudo` to reach the desired style, adding `.flag` to any `li` will create the flag in the correct position, (*For me I prefer this solution*), check below:

```css
.flag {
  position: relative;
}
.flag::after {
    content: 'AF';
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 12px;
    background: violet;
    padding: 3px 6px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    top: 7px;
    right: 7px;
    z-index: 99;
}
div {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 10px
}

ul {
  color: White;
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul li {
  position: relative;
  font: bold italic 22px/1.7 Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
  background: #34495E ;
}

ul li:nth-of-type(odd) {
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
  background: #283747;
}

h3 {
  padding-left: 100px;
  font: 16px/1.2 Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
  margin: 0px;
}

li p {
  font: 12px/1.5 Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding-left: 100px;
  color: #D0D3D4 ;
  margin: 0;
}

li:hover {
  background: #7D6608;
  cursor: pointer;
}

li:hover:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background: #7D6608;
  cursor: pointer;
}

span {
  position: absolute;
}

.scene_break {
  background: yellow;   
  font: 18px/1.7 Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
  color: black;
}

.scene_break:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background: yellow;   
  font: 18px/1.7 Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
  color: black;
}

li.live_cue {
  border: 4px solid yellow;
}

.cue_af {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #7E009A; /* Changing background color */
    font-weight: bold; /* Making font bold */
    border-radius: 5px; /* Making border radius */
    width: auto; /* Making auto-sizable width */
    height: auto; /* Making auto-sizable height */
    padding: 0px 3px 0px 3px; /* Making space around letters */
    font-size: 12px; /* Changing font size */  
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li class="flag"><span>71</span>'+
<h3>Test description</h3>
<p>time: 0s</p>
</li>
<li><span>71</span>'+
<h3>Test description</h3>
<p>time: 0s</p>
</li>
<li><span>71</span>'+
<h3>Test description</h3>
<p>time: 0s</p>
</li>
<li><span>71</span>'+
<h3>Test description</h3>
<p>time: 0s</p>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

check this snippet code, I think this is what you wanted, When you click on an item, that item is selected and the "AF" is displayed on it, and if you click on an item that has the "AF", the word "AF" is deleted.

```js
const onSelectedItem = (element) => {
        if (element.classList.contains('selected'))
            element.classList.remove('selected'); else element.classList.add('selected')
}
```

```css
  div {
        width: 500px;
        margin: 10px
    }

    ul {
        color: White;
        list-style-type: none;
    }

    ul li {
        position: relative;
        font: bold italic 22px/1.7 Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
        margin: 0 0 0 0;
        padding: 0 0 0 0;
        background: #34495E ;
    }

    ul li:nth-of-type(odd) {
        margin: 0 0 0 0;
        padding: 0 0 0 0;
        background: #283747;
    }

    h3 {
        padding-left: 100px;
        font: 16px/1.2 Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
        margin: 0px;
    }

    li p {
        font: 12px/1.5 Helvetica, sans-serif;
        padding-left: 100px;
        color: #D0D3D4 ;
        margin: 0;
    }

    li:hover {
        background: #7D6608;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    li:hover:nth-of-type(odd) {
        background: #7D6608;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    span {
        position: absolute;
    }

    .scene_break {
        background: yellow;
        font: 18px/1.7 Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
        color: black;
    }

    .scene_break:nth-of-type(odd) {
        background: yellow;
        font: 18px/1.7 Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
        color: black;
    }

    li.live_cue {
        border: 4px solid yellow;
    }

    .cue_af {
        display: none;
        background-color: #7E009A; /* Changing background color */
        font-weight: bold; /* Making font bold */
        border-radius: 5px; /* Making border radius */
        width: auto; /* Making auto-sizable width */
        height: auto; /* Making auto-sizable height */
        padding: 0px 3px 0px 3px; /* Making space around letters */
        font-size: 12px; /* Changing font size */
    }

    .selected .cue_af {
        display: inline-block !important;
    }
```

```html
<ul>
    <li onclick='onSelectedItem(this)'><span>71</span>'+
        <h3>Test description</h3>
        <p>time: 0s</p>
        <p class='cue_af'>AF</p>
    </li>

        <li onclick='onSelectedItem(this)'><span>71</span>'+
        <h3>Test description</h3>
        <p>time: 0s</p>
        <p class='cue_af'>AF</p>
    </li>

        <li onclick='onSelectedItem(this)'><span>71</span>'+
        <h3>Test description</h3>
        <p>time: 0s</p>
        <p class='cue_af'>AF</p>
    </li>

        <li onclick='onSelectedItem(this)'><span>71</span>'+
        <h3>Test description</h3>
        <p>time: 0s</p>
        <p class='cue_af'>AF</p>
    </li>

        <li onclick='onSelectedItem(this)'><span>71</span>'+
        <h3>Test description</h3>
        <p>time: 0s</p>
        <p class='cue_af'>AF</p>
    </li>

        <li onclick='onSelectedItem(this)'><span>71</span>'+
        <h3>Test description</h3>
        <p>time: 0s</p>
        <p class='cue_af'>AF</p>
    </li>

        <li onclick='onSelectedItem(this)'><span>71</span>'+
        <h3>Test description</h3>
        <p>time: 0s</p>
        <p class='cue_af'>AF</p>
    </li>

        <li onclick='onSelectedItem(this)'><span>71</span>'+
        <h3>Test description</h3>
        <p>time: 0s</p>
        <p class='cue_af'>AF</p>
    </li>

        <li onclick='onSelectedItem(this)'><span>71</span>'+
        <h3>Test description</h3>
        <p>time: 0s</p>
        <p class='cue_af'>AF</p>
    </li>

        <li onclick='onSelectedItem(this)'><span>71</span>'+
        <h3>Test description</h3>
        <p>time: 0s</p>
        <p class='cue_af'>AF</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```